# Theon's words in season 3 episode 4

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In season 3 episode 4 of *Game of Thrones*, what did Theon mean when he said:

> My real father lost his head at King's landing

Answer (score 26):

This can only mean that Theon has realized that Lord Eddard Stark was more of a father to him than Balon Grayjoy, his biological father.

As far as I remember, Theon does not say this in the books. He does show some remorse for what he has done, but he does not go as far as claim that Ned Stark was his real father.

Comment: thanks i've also read the books and Theon does not say those words

Comment: I think they really want to try and push the viewer to sympathy for Theon for what is to come...

Comment: One of the reasons you won't find this in the book is that they never really covered his torture and subsequent transformation. However, for the show, rather than give him some time off, they've decided to tell that story.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P I don't understand why though, because these scenes are becoming repetitive...

Comment: @Kalissar: The reason will be clear eventually. I'm trying to avoid spoilers, but suffice to say that I'm a fan of what the end result of this torture.

Answer (score 6):

By saying this, he admits that **he considers that his real father was Lord Eddard Stark**, the man who raised him during the last 10 years, and not Balon Greyjoy, his biological father.